# NGRX - Subscription from child component to app.component

Tags: ngrx

I have to show footercomponet on  app-component conditionally based on child component data. I am subscribing from app component global store update and when child  component is updating the store I am not seeing the app component subscription getting fired. I am using angular 6 below is the prototype of code on app component.

Code- AppComponent - >

```
public ngOnInit(): void {      
this.subscriptions.push(this.store.pipe(select(showFooterFun)).subscribe(showfooter => {
      this.showLegalFooter = showfooter;
    }));
}
```

Child component -  I have child component updating the global store with boolean value to show Hide footer. Is it possible to invoke app.component subscription from child by updating global store.

Answer (score 0):

Please don't `subscribe`, this is often the case some things do not work.
Instead, use Angular's built-in `async` pipe.
Also make sure you're modifying your state inside reducers in a pure way.

```
// in typescript
showFooter$ = this.store.pipe(select(showFooterFun);

// in html
<div *ngIf="showFooter$ | async">
Footer
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Thankyou timdeschryver for your response/suggestion much appreciated well I haven't tried the approach you have suggested but on further debugging I observed that in my case due to exception in app component **ngOnInit** the subscription was getting unsubscribe, by putting null check I observed it got resolved.

```
this.subscriptions.push(this.store.pipe(select(showLegalFooter)).subscribe(showfooter => {
  if (showfooter) { //null check resolved the issue
    this.showFooter = showfooter.showFooter; //earlier when showfooter was null //which lead to exception and the suscription got unsuscribe.
              }
}));
```